# Import Lottie-player + Lottiefiles plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress, lottie

I'm using [lottie-player](https://docs.lottiefiles.com/lottie-player/) from Lottiefiles in a WordPress project.

Also, I have [the official Lottiefiles](https://wordpress.org/plugins/lottiefiles/) plugin installed.

The problem I'm having is that when importing lottie-player in my app:

```
import '@lottiefiles/lottie-player';
```

It tells me no, because it is already registered by the plugin. I can't use both the lottie-player library and the plugin at the same time. Is there any way I can use both at the same time?

Comment: Without knowing your use-case, I’ll mention that I have used the `lottie-player` library without the plugin several times. If your use-case does require both, then this is more of a JavaScript naming problem than a WordPress one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have the LottieFiles plugin you can access to the player with no need of importing again. Just remove the `import '@lottiefiles/lottie-player'` and it should work.

Comment: Funciona. Muchas gracias, Javier.